# Facebook Graph API: how to read feed of Facebook groups that I don't manage?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook has a very useful API that can be used to get the feed of a Facebook group (see [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v12.0/group/feed)). One of the requirements for using this API is that my app must be installed in the group. As far as I know, I can install apps only in groups that I manage.

My question is how can I get the feed of a group by an API, if I don't manage the group? Is is possible by Graph API or by any other piece of software?

Comment: The only option is to have the admin of the group install your app.